# Graph ignores x-axis

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to plot 2 graphs on the same x-axis.

```
plt.plot(df_delay.D, df_delay.Q/100,df_delay.P/100)
plt.xlabel('Delay')
plt.ylabel('Transaction Confirmation (ms)')
major_ticks_delay = np.arange(1, 2, 2)
plt.yticks(major_ticks_delay)
plt.ticklabel_format(style='plain')
```

[image]

The first one (HBBFT) behaves as expected, while the second one completed i

gnores the x-axis and is truncated.

I am unsure why this is happening and will appreciate any help around this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to presume you wanted df_delay.D (x) vs df_delay.Q/100 (y) and df_delay.D(x) vs df_delay.Q/100 (y):

```
plt.plot(df_delay.D, df_delay.Q/100) #first line
plt.plot(df_delay.D, df_delay.P/100) #second line

plt.xlabel('Delay')
plt.ylabel('Transaction Confirmation (ms)')
major_ticks_delay = np.arange(1, 2, 2)
plt.yticks(major_ticks_delay)
plt.ticklabel_format(style='plain')
```

They will be the same color unless you specify different colors for each line.